# Where can I find the wallpaper used in safe mode?

Tags: macos, wallpaper

It looks really cool. I don't think it's just solid black and therefore can't find it in the standard Apple wallpapers through `System Preferences`. So where is this wallpaper stored?

Comment: Are you asking where it is stored, how it is created or something else?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to use it in normal mode. @nohillside

Comment: Please edit the question then to be specific about what you are asking for (and what you want to accomplish).

Comment: @nohillside Yes, sir.